# URI::URL Not Getting Parameter

Tags: perl, url, module

```
# The url I'm on: https://development.cherrylanekeepsakes.com/cgi-bin/employees.cgi?action=edit_timeclock_dashboard&id=80&start_date=2012-09-01&end_date=2012-09-16&print_view=1
use URI::URL;
use Data::Dumper;
my $url = URI::URL->new( '' . $cgi->new->url(-path_info => 1, -query => 1) );
warn Dumper($url->params('print_view'));
```

It gives me nothing. What am I doing wrong? This seems like a pretty simple task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason you're using [URI::URL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aURL) instead of [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI)? It's an obsolete module that only exists for backwards compatibility. It's not even documented, so I can't even confirm that `params` is suppose to do what you think it does.

What follows is a solution using the module that replaced URI::URL. It's even part of the same distribution.

```
use URI qw( );
my $url = URI->new('https://...');
my %query_form = $url->query_form();
say $query_form{print_view};
```

Or better yet,

```
use URI             qw( );
use URI::QueryParam qw( );
my $url = URI->new('https://...');
say $url->query_param('print_view');
```

Note: To assign one of the value of `query_param` to a scalar, you need to use parens as follows:

```
my ($print_view) = $url->query_param('print_view');
```

Answer (score 1):

As per @ikegami's recommendation, I am now using URI, instead of obsolete URL::URI.

```
# https://development.cherrylanekeepsakes.com/cgi-bin/employees.cgi?action=edit_timeclock_dashboard&id=80&start_date=2012-09-01&end_date=2012-09-16&print_view=1
use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

my $url = URI->new('' . $cgi->new->url(-path_info => 1, -query => 1));

warn $url->query_param('print_view'); # prints 1 as expected
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code displays nothing is that your URL has no `param` fields - only a set of `query` fields.

A URL looks roughly like

```
scheme://host:port/path1/path2;param1;param2?query1=A&query2=B#fragment
```

and there are no semicolons in your URL